# IN EXCEL REPLACING DATA FROM ONE CELL ADD THAT DATA TO DATA ON ANOTHER CELL

Tags: excel

I have about 500 plus items I would like to take info from one column and replace it with another text 
example 
column 1 has **`110573`** 
column 2 has **`pm_fm_fk = ''`** 
I want to take column 1 add it to column 2 so it reads **`pm_fm_fk = '110573'`** then I would like to be able to duplicate that down the whole sheet column one has diffrent text so each line is unique 
can this be done in excel?

Comment: are there always two single quotes in column 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to enclose the 1st column's value in the quotes, then I suggest you to try this:

```
=LEFT(B1;LEN(B1)-1)&A1&RIGHT(B1;1)
```

**note: you might have to replace `;` with `,` depending on your local settings**

This assumes that `A1` has `110573` and `B1` has `pm_fm_fk='`

> It takes everything but the last character from B1 => `pm_fm_fk='`
>
> adds A1 to it => `pm_fm_fk='110573`
>
> and closes it off by the last char in B1 => `pm_fm_fk='110573'`

Answer (score 0):

In the cell next to those two (say they are in columns A and B), have this formula and copy it down

```
=B1&A1
```